# Can Denji return to human form at will?

Tags: chainsaw-man

Denji can retract the hand blades as we saw in *Chainsaw Man* S1E3 but we also saw in S1E1 that he can fully return to human form only when there is human contact (Denji's devil parts melted on Makima's contact). Can Denji also retract the head blade also so he can return to be human on his own without needing any external human contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Denji does have the ability to return to his human form. However only when he remains his conscious self.

The only instance when Denji loses control is when he unlocks the true form of the "Chainsaw Devil" and begins to decimate his enemies whilst forcefully taking Kobeni out on a date.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I couldn't understand your second para. Is this your own viewpoint? If not, please include information that is canon to source material. I haven't read the manga so, can't confirm if what is said is true.